# how to install DBD-SQLite in centos 7 perl v5.34.0

Tags: sqlite, perl, dbi

I am try to install DBD-SQLite V1.70 module of perl in centos7. I have tried `cpanm DBD::SQLite` or download from the https://metacpan.org/dist/DBD-SQLite.
every time will be install error in "DBI 1.57 is required to configure this module; please install it or upgrade your CPAN/CPANPLUS shell." But in fact , I have install DBI V1.643.

```
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.62)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0.82 ... Yes (3.80)
Checking if you have DBI 1.57 ... Yes (1.643)
```

DBI 1.57 is too old, I cannot install it in the perl V5.34.

Comment: Is DBI installed through the OS package manager, or cpanm?

Comment: Have you tried to run `cpan DBI`?

Comment: If you can communicate with sysadmin of your system then ask him to install sqlite module for you `yum install perl-DBD-SQLite` or for CentOS 8 `dnf install perl-DBD-SQLite`.

Comment: That means 1.57 *or newer*

Answer (score 0):

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/perl-DBD-SQLite-1.39-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html - I suggest you to install it as a package, not from the CPAN.

Comment: no root install it is difficulty.So i always install perl module by cpanm. this error may be course of my DBI install error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error course of DBI not install successful. I run `perl -MDBI -E 'say DBI->VERSION'` to check DBI version, but output a empty line. I recheck my PATH found that I have installed another DBI from rpm, and add the install PATH to `~/.bashrc`. After I delete the PATH from my `~/.bashrc`, and reinstall DBI by `cpanm DBI`, it worked. and run `cpanm DBD::SQLite` install DBD-SQLite successful.